# Replace period surrounded by characters with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace certain periods within a text file using sed. My file is something like this:

```
a.b
aa.bb
aa. b
a . b
```

What I'm trying to do is to replace the periods that have characters right before and right after them with a '§'. In this case, "a.b" and "aa.bb".
I've managed to do it with grep and then sed:

```
egrep '[[:alpha:]]\.[[:alpha:]]' | sed 's/\./§/g'
```

But that won't let me continue to manipulate the file. And if I try

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]\.[[:alpha:]]/§/g'
```

it would replace a string like "a.b" to "§" instead of "a§b".

Help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "catch" the parts and then print them again.

```
sed 's/\([[:alpha:]]\)\.\([[:alpha:]]\)/\1§\2/g'
```

Format `\([[:alpha:]]\)\.\([[:alpha:]]\)` indicates `XXX.YYY`. Then you print them with `\1§\2`, being `\1` the first part, `\2` the second... wrapped in between `\( ... \)`.

If you want further information, this reference may help you: [RegExp - keeping parts of a pattern in sed](http://gilmation.com/articles/regexp-keeping-parts-of-a-pattern-in-sed/)

Comment: @Roadhouse, if this answer or kch's solved your problem, consider accepting one of them so it is clear your issue is finished and it is useful for next people entering in this page.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `sed` doesn't like me, but here's the same thing with `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/(\w)\.(\w)/$1§$2/g'
```

The regexp feature that you're looking for is called "captures".

Update: for some reason `-E` was required for `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/([[:alpha:]])\.([[:alpha:]])/\1§\2/g'
```