# Using sed to remove period at the end of string (zip code)

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file of addresses that I am attempting to scrub and I am using `sed` to get rid of unwanted charachters and formatting.  In this case, I have zip codes followed by a period:

```
Mr. John Doe
Exclusively Stuff, 186 
Caravelle Drive, Ponte Vedra FL
33487.
```

(for the time being, ignore the new lines; I am just focusing on the zip and period for now)

I want to remove the period (.) from the zip as my first step in cleaning this up.  I tried to use sub strings in sed as follows (using "|" as a delimiter - it easier for me to see):

```
sed 's|\([0-9]{4}\)\.|\1|g' test.txt
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't remove the period.  It just prints it out as part of the sub string based on this post: 
 [Replace period surrounded by characters with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147458/replace-period-surrounded-by-characters-with-sed)

A point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified 4 digits `{4}` but have 5 and you have to escape the `{` and `}`, for example:

```
sed 's|\(^[0-9]\{5\}\).*|\1|g' test.txt
```

Notice that you also have a space after the dot, so you might want to trim everything following five digits but to be safe you might want to specify that they must be at start of line `^`.

In my case, if I type `info sed` which is more complete than `man sed`, I find this:

```
'-r'
'--regexp-extended'
     Use extended regular expressions rather than basic regular
     expressions.  Extended regexps are those that 'egrep' accepts; they
     can be clearer because they usually have less backslashes, but are
     a GNU extension and hence scripts that use them are not portable.
     *Note Extended regular expressions: Extended regexps.
```

And under `Appendix A Extended regular expressions` you can read:

```
The only difference between basic and extended regular expressions is in
the behavior of a few characters: '?', '+', parentheses, braces ('{}'),
and '|'.  While basic regular expressions require these to be escaped if
you want them to behave as special characters, when using extended
regular expressions you must escape them if you want them _to match a
literal character_.  '|' is special here because '\|' is a GNU extension
- standard basic regular expressions do not provide its functionality.

Examples:
'abc?'
     becomes 'abc\?' when using extended regular expressions.  It
     matches the literal string 'abc?'.

'c\+'
     becomes 'c+' when using extended regular expressions.  It matches
     one or more 'c's.

'a\{3,\}'
     becomes 'a{3,}' when using extended regular expressions.  It
     matches three or more 'a's.

 '\(abc\)\{2,3\}'
     becomes '(abc){2,3}' when using extended regular expressions.  It
     matches either 'abcabc' or 'abcabcabc'.

 '\(abc*\)\1'
     becomes '(abc*)\1' when using extended regular expressions.
     Backreferences must still be escaped when using extended regular
     expressions.
```

Comment: That works - can you expand as to why I need to escape the brackets?  The sed tutorial I was using made no mention of it.

Comment: @Allan: if you use GNU sed and switch to extended regexp with option `-E` you can use this: `sed -E 's|([0-9]{5})\.|\1|'  test.txt`

Comment: @ Glad it work, I updated my answer to include more info. Hope is helpful.

Comment: @archimiro - If I could only upvote more than once.  Thank you for that.

Comment: This will incorrectly match street addresses such as `12345 Exclusively Stuff, 186 `. I know it's not in the OP's corpus, but it's a pretty likely input on any real data set.

Comment: @CodeGnome  Thanks for the feedback! I don't know about that structure of addresses I live in Colombia and are very different, so I just answer according to OP's question, not according to structure of expected addresses or zip codes. Thank you for the useful input!

Comment: @CodeGnome - I have a data set that was captured from OCR, but thankfully, it's fairly consistent.  My goal is to create a CSV file with an address entry on each line.

Answer (score 1):

### Basic Solution: Use a Range Atom to Handle Your Posted Input

An easy (but slightly naive) way to do this with your posted input is to look for:

1. start of line
2. followed by exactly 5 digits (a standard US ZIP Code)
3. followed by zero or more characters (e.g. a ZIP+4)
4. followed by zero or more non-period characters (don't match a street address)
5. followed by a literal period

and just replace the whole match with the captured part of the match. For example:

- With BSD sed or without extended expressions:

  ```
  sed 's/^\([[:digit:]]\{5\}[^.]*\)\./\1/'
  ```
- With GNU sed and extended regular expressions:

  ```
  sed -r 's/^([[:digit:]]{5}[^.]*)\./\1/'
  ```

Either way, given your posted input you end up with:

```
Mr. John Doe
Exclusively Stuff, 186 
Caravelle Drive, Ponte Vedra FL
33487
```

### Advanced Solution: Handle ZIP Codes Properly

The main caveat is that the solution above works with your posted sample, but won't match if the ZIP Code is properly at the end of the last line of the address as it should be in a [standardized USPS address](https://pe.usps.com/text/pub28/28c2_001.htm). That's fine if you've got a custom format, but it will likely cause you problems with standardized or corrected addresses such as:

```
Mr. John Doe
12345 Exclusively Stuff, 186 
Caravelle Drive, Ponte Vedra FL 33487.
```

The following will work with both your posted input and a more typical USPS address, but your mileage on other non-standard inputs may vary.

```
# More reliable, but much harder to read.
sed -r 's/([[:digit:]]{5}(-[[:digit:]]{4})?[[:space:]]*)\.[[:space:]]*$/\1/'
```